# Como fazer esse FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, floatingactionbutton

Olá, no meu projeto que gostaria de poder fazer um FloatingActionButton que ao clicar nele ele esvanecesse a tela de fundo e exibe acima mais 3 FloatingActionButton com a sua respectiva legenda do lado. Como se os 3 outros FloatingActionButton fossem subbutões do primeiro.

Eu poderia declarar cada um dos FloatingActionButton no layout individualmente com suas animações e posicionamentos, mas será que tem outro meio? Alguém tem uma dica de como posso fazer?

Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você vai ter que definir todos os FABs no xml, mas deixar apenas um visível, e quando o usuário clicar no FAB visível, você mostra os demais. Segue um exemplo:

**Criando o layout**

```
...
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
...
```

**Definindo a animação**

res/anim/fab_open.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

res/anim/fab_close.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="0.8"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

res/anim/rotate_forward.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

res/anim/rotate_backward.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

**Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
    private FloatingActionButton fab,fab1,fab2;
    private Animation fab_open,fab_close,rotate_forward,rotate_backward;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
        rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.fab:

                animateFAB();
                break;
            case R.id.fab1:

                Log.d("Raj", "Fab 1");
                break;
            case R.id.fab2:

                Log.d("Raj", "Fab 2");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void animateFAB(){

        if(isFabOpen){

            fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
            fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab1.setClickable(false);
            fab2.setClickable(false);
            isFabOpen = false;
            Log.d("Raj", "close");

        } else {

            fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
            fab1.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab1.setClickable(true);
            fab2.setClickable(true);
            isFabOpen = true;
            Log.d("Raj","open");

        }
    }
}
```

Esse tutorial completo você pode acessar [nesse link.](https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado, chegando em casa vou testar. Mais ou menos o que eu já ia fazer mesmo.

Comment: Nesse caso o layout de trás fica esvanecido?

Comment: Isso. No arquivo xml, a linha responsável por isso é a android:visibility="invisible"